# How can I assign a php return value without causing my sql to run twice?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am making a wordpress plugin that deals with forms.

I have a form that upon submit, a function is called to insert the values into the DB.

From that function, I am returning the clientID value which was auto Incremented.

I then assign that returned value to a new variable in a new form on the same page.

It works, but I am getting two DB inserts now. IT seems when I assign the new Variable to the function, it runs the insert statement twice.

What I am trying to accomplish is to insert the user into the first table within a function and return just the Clients ID so I can than use the ID for another table insert.

Any help would be appreciated.

The form which on submit calls the function to insert into DB

```
<form action="" id="new_client_form" method="POST" onsubmit="return submit_new_client()">
```

The function which contains DB code and returns Client ID

```
function submit_new_client () {

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      /////
    $insertClient = $db -> exec("INSERT INTO client SET .......");

    $clientId = $db -> lastInsertId();

    echo $clientId .'Is the New client ID';//This is printing the correct ID(used for testing)

}
return $clientId;
}
add_action('init', 'submit_new_client');
```

The new form/ Where I assigned the variable to the function

```
<?php
  $client = submit_new_client();
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "<p>The Client Id is</p>";
      echo "$client";
    } else {
     echo "<p>No client ID</p>";
     }
 ?>
```

For example, Once the form is submitted I will get an Echo from the function saying the Client ID is 32. But when I go down to the next form it will say the Client ID is 33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, in the HTML form, you have `onsubmit="return submit_new_client()`. The `onsubmit` attribute is used to call a Javascript function, not a PHP function, so I'm surprised the PHP function is being called at all.

Is it possible for you to post the code in its entirety?

Edit: I did a brief search on the `add_action` function you're calling. Are you sure that this call isn't calling your submit_new_client() function at some point? See the documentation I found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out for me. For some reason I thought the correct way was to put my code in functions on the main plugin file and call it from my include files. I ended up just taking it out of the function and putting the if(isset$_POST[]){} on the same file as my forms and it works perfectly. Appreciate your answer! pointed me in the right direction.